# "Купил шапку В подарок" или "Купил шапку НА подарок"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, предлоги

Последнее время вижу на форумах и в отзывах в магазинах фразу типа "брал на подарок". Правильно ли это? Или все же "брал в подарок"?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел один пример в Нацкорпусе:

*Я покупаю все это впрок, на подарки, ибо много разъезжаю, и повсюду у меня друзья, приятели и знакомцы. ) [Дина Рубина. Медная шкатулка (сборник) (2015)]*

Смысл здесь особый: купить вещь, чтобы она послужила подарком когда-нибудь в будущем. Думаю, это ОЧЕНЬ разговорное выражение. Его более нейтральный аналог: "**Купил для подарка**".

А когда сразу же в понедельник собрался докупить еще для себя и **для подарков** ― приобретение было безупречным, ― никаких следов субботнего беспорядка в торговом зале не осталось, Тарас даже решил, что ошибся этажом, ― а в такую же рубашку, слегка другого цвета, но стоимостью уже пятьдесят пять франков был одет пластмассовый манекен. [Ольга Новикова. Мужской роман (1999)]

Если моя книга «1001 вопрос про ЭТО» вам понравилась и вы бы хотели купить ее **для подарка** своим друзьям, то вы можете заказать книгу в «Бета-сервис». [Владимир Шахиджанян. 1001 вопрос про ЭТО (№№ 501-1001) (1999)]

― Нет, еще поехал на дачу, потом Оля позвонила ― сессия, поехал регистрироваться, получил деньги, накупил книг и шариковок и кое-что **для подарков**, а уж потом катнул, но в день, когда шла сессия, уехал, оставив Оле записку, что «могло быть хуже», а здесь начал «тянуть проволоку», сквозь кот[орую] помню звонок Bopoнкова насчет Дементьева с Заксом, потом приезд Вали с «поправкой» для меня и отчаянной просьбой держаться , а потом ― Дементьев, многоступенчатое сообщение о том, что М[ихаил] Андр[еевич] поговорит со мной и чтобы я ему позвонил. [А. Т. Твардовский. Рабочие тетради 60-х годов (1967) // «Знамя», 2002]

А тебе, так как ты покупаешь ткани **для подарка** бедным ламам, я уступлю еще 20% и отдам по той цене, по которой покупаю его сам в России. [В. А. Обручев. В дебрях Центральной Азии (1951)]

---

А вот еще одна находка, старинная:

*Напишите, какая бы из 9 книжек «Bibliotheque blanche» Гетцеля, выпущенных на подарки в 1879 г. [П. В. Анненков. Письма И. С. Тургеневу (1875-1883)]*

Но смысл тот же: эти книжки станут подарками, но кому и когда их подарят — не определено.

---

Дополнение

По поводу "Купил в подарок". По-моему, когда вы говорите "в подарок" необходимо указать (или хотя бы подразумевать") **в подарок кому** куплена вещь. Впрочем, я задал на эту тему отдельный вопрос:
["В подарок” или “для подарка”?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437252/%d0%92-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

Грамотно звучит "в подарок" вместо "на подарок", но "для подарков" вместо "в подарки" или "на подарки".