# "В подарок” или “для подарка”?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Вот цитаты из ответов справочной службы русского языка (Грамота.ру), которые поставили меня в тупик:

А если человек в магазине выбрал супницу **в подарок**, и его друг говорит: "Эта супница некрасивая..." ([Вопрос № 295041](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=295041))

Хотите купить постельное бельё **в подарок** дешево – присмотритесь к бязевым комплектам.([Вопрос № 286012](http://%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%20%E2%84%96%20286012))

Мне всегда казалось, что после слов *в подарок* должно идти указание, в подарок **кому** (или хотя бы подразумеваться). В приведенных примерах этого нет и в помине. Почему же справочная служба не предлагает заменить *в подарок* на *для подарка* (именно последнее, как мне кажется, подходит для данных ситуаций)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что при использовании формы "в подарок" требуется указание лица, которому подарок предназначен  **(в виде подлежащего или дополнения в Д.п).**:

**Я получил** книгу  **в подарок.** Я купил книгу **другу в подарок**.

Форма "для подарка" указания адресата не требует: Я купил книгу **для подарка.**

Поэтому выражение вида  "выбрал книгу в подарок" **мне кажется неточным**, но оно всё-таки используется в разговорной речи, например:  Но я его покупал **в подарок**, поэтому сборка не потребовалась.

Кстати, **иногда адресат ясен из контекста или из ситуации**, поэтому используется сочетание "в подарок".

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что необходимость зависимого слова при сочетании "в подарок" **зависит от контекста**. Например, в беседе с продавцом покупатель *не обязан* сообщать, в подарок *кому* из своих близких он выбирает товар. Он вполне может сказать так в объяснение своей придирчивисти к мелким дефектам упаковки и т. п. - **в каком качестве** ему понадобится покупаемый предмет (он покупается **в подарок**), и совсем не обязательно высказывать это в форме "**для чего** он это покупает". Такую же форму и похожие особенности употребления имеет сочетание "**в долг**" - не обязательно говорить, кому: "у меня этих денег уже нет, *я отдал их в долг* (не скажу кому - из этических соображений)". Поэтому не просматривается роковой необходимости *всегда* уточнять "кому" или заменять "в подарок" на другое выражение.

В двух примерах из вопроса есть смысловые неясности. В первом возникает вопрос: вмешавшийся друг - это тот, кому в подарок покупают (тогда так и сказать надо было: "... в подарок другу, а тот и говорит..."), или просто за компанию в магазин зашёл? Во втором примере, похожем на рекламное обращение, возникает мысль: о подарке упоминается по случаю какой-то скидки, подарок *себе* предлагают сделать? Поэтому и здесь напрашивается уточнение:

> Хотите *дешево купить* постельное бельё в подарок *своим близким* –
>   присмотритесь к бязевым комплектам.

Comment: По ссылке из первого вопроса контекст совершенно очевиден. И как Вы считаете, Грамота.ру верно использовала выражение "выбрал в подарок" в этом контексте? Из Вашего ответа это не совсем понятно.

Comment: Нет: в связи с присутсвием в контексте "друга" здесь нужно было дополнить это выражение, пояснив, ему или кому-то другому выбирался подарок.